# How to implement a custom presenter in a Windows UWP (Xamarin, MvvmCross)

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, uwp

I have the following code in my Android app, it basically uses one page (using a NavigationDrawer) and swaps fragments in/out of the central view. This allows the navigation to occur on one page instead of many pages:

Setup.cs:

```
    protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()
    {
        var customPresenter = new MvxFragmentsPresenter();
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxFragmentsPresenter>(customPresenter);
        return customPresenter;
    }
```

ShellPage.cs

```
    public class ShellPage : MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity<ShellPageViewModel>, IMvxFragmentHost
    {
        .
        .
        .

        public bool Show(MvxViewModelRequest request, Bundle bundle)
        {
            if (request.ViewModelType == typeof(MenuContentViewModel))
            {
                ShowFragment(request.ViewModelType.Name, Resource.Id.navigation_frame, bundle);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                ShowFragment(request.ViewModelType.Name, Resource.Id.content_frame, bundle, true);
                return true;
            }
        }

        public bool Close(IMvxViewModel viewModel)
        {
            CloseFragment(viewModel.GetType().Name, Resource.Id.content_frame);
            return true;
        }

        .
        .
        .
    }
```

How can I achieve the same behavior in a Windows UWP app? Or rather, is there ANY example that exists for a Windows MvvmCross app which implements a CustomPresenter? That may at least give me a start as to how to implement it.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I'm finally starting to figure out how to go about this with a customer presenter:

```
    public class CustomPresenter : IMvxWindowsViewPresenter
    {
        IMvxWindowsFrame _rootFrame;

        public CustomPresenter(IMvxWindowsFrame rootFrame)
        {
            _rootFrame = rootFrame;
        }

        public void AddPresentationHintHandler<THint>(Func<THint, bool> action) where THint : MvxPresentationHint
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void ChangePresentation(MvxPresentationHint hint)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
        {
            if (request.ViewModelType == typeof(ShellPageViewModel))
            {
                //_rootFrame?.Navigate(typeof(ShellPage), null);    // throws an exception

                ((Frame)_rootFrame.UnderlyingControl).Content = new ShellPage();
            }
        }
    }
```

When I try to do a navigation to the ShellPage, it fails. So when I set the Content to the ShellPage it works, but the ShellPage's ViewModel is not initialized automatically when I do it that way. I'm guessing ViewModels are initialized in MvvmCross using OnNavigatedTo ???

Comment: try using a **ContentPresenter**

Comment: I need to know how to manage navigation with the MvxWindowsStorePage in MvvmCross.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, and built a custom presenter for UWP. It loans a couple of ideas from an Android sample I found somewhere, which uses fragments. The idea is as follows.

I have a container view which can contain multiple sub-views with their own ViewModels. So I want to be able to present multiple views within the container.

***Note:*** I'm using MvvmCross 4.0.0-beta3

**Presenter**

```
using System;
using Cirrious.CrossCore;
using Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Views;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsUWP.Views;
using xxxxx.WinUniversal.Extensions;

namespace xxxxx.WinUniversal.Presenters
{
    public class MvxWindowsMultiRegionViewPresenter
        : MvxWindowsViewPresenter
    {
        private readonly IMvxWindowsFrame _rootFrame;

        public MvxWindowsMultiRegionViewPresenter(IMvxWindowsFrame rootFrame)
            : base(rootFrame)
        {
            _rootFrame = rootFrame;
        }

        public override async void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
        {
            var host = _rootFrame.Content as IMvxMultiRegionHost;
            var view = CreateView(request);

            if (host != null && view.HasRegionAttribute())
            {
                host.Show(view as MvxWindowsPage);
            }
            else
            {
                base.Show(request);
            }
        }

        private static IMvxWindowsView CreateView(MvxViewModelRequest request)
        {
            var viewFinder = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewsContainer>();

            var viewType = viewFinder.GetViewType(request.ViewModelType);
            if (viewType == null)
                throw new MvxException("View Type not found for " + request.ViewModelType);

            // Create instance of view
            var viewObject = Activator.CreateInstance(viewType);
            if (viewObject == null)
                throw new MvxException("View not loaded for " + viewType);

            var view = viewObject as IMvxWindowsView;
            if (view == null)
                throw new MvxException("Loaded View is not a IMvxWindowsView " + viewType);

            view.ViewModel = LoadViewModel(request);

            return view;
        }

        private static IMvxViewModel LoadViewModel(MvxViewModelRequest request)
        {
            // Load the viewModel
            var viewModelLoader = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader>();

            return viewModelLoader.LoadViewModel(request, null);
        }
    }
}
```

**IMvxMultiRegionHost**

```
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsUWP.Views;

namespace xxxxx.WinUniversal.Presenters
{
    public interface IMvxMultiRegionHost
    {
        void Show(MvxWindowsPage view);

        void CloseViewModel(IMvxViewModel viewModel);

        void CloseAll();
    }
}
```

**RegionAttribute**

```
using System;

namespace xxxxx.WinUniversal.Presenters
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public sealed class RegionAttribute
        : Attribute
    {
        public RegionAttribute(string regionName)
        {
            Name = regionName;
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

These are the three foundational classes you need. Next you'll need to implement the `IMvxMultiRegionHost` in a `MvxWindowsPage` derived class.

This is the one I'm using:

**HomeView.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsUWP.Views;
using xxxxx.Shared.Controls;
using xxxxx.WinUniversal.Extensions;
using xxxxx.WinUniversal.Presenters;
using xxxxx.Core.ViewModels;

namespace xxxxx.WinUniversal.Views
{
    public partial class HomeView
        : MvxWindowsPage
        , IMvxMultiRegionHost
    {
        public HomeView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // ...

        public void Show(MvxWindowsPage view)
        {
            if (!view.HasRegionAttribute())
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "View was expected to have a RegionAttribute, but none was specified.");

            var regionName = view.GetRegionName();

            RootSplitView.Content = view;
        }

        public void CloseViewModel(IMvxViewModel viewModel)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void CloseAll()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

The last piece to make this work is the way the actual xaml in the view is set-up. You'll notice that I'm using a `SplitView` control, and that I'm replacing the Content property with the new View that's coming in in the `ShowView` method on the `HomeView` class.

**HomeView.xaml**

```
<SplitView x:Name="RootSplitView"
           DisplayMode="CompactInline"
           IsPaneOpen="false"
           CompactPaneLength="48"
           OpenPaneLength="200">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        // Some ListView with menu items.
    </SplitView.Pane>
    <SplitView.Content>
        // Initial content..
    </SplitView.Content>
</SplitView>
```

---

**EDIT:**

**Extension Methods**

I forgot to post the two extension methods to determine if the view declares a `[Region]` attribute.

```
public static class RegionAttributeExtentionMethods
{
    public static bool HasRegionAttribute(this IMvxWindowsView view)
    {
        var attributes = view
            .GetType()
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RegionAttribute), true);

        return attributes.Any();
    }

    public static string GetRegionName(this IMvxWindowsView view)
    {
        var attributes = view
            .GetType()
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RegionAttribute), true);

        if (!attributes.Any())
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The IMvxView has no region attribute.");

        return ((RegionAttribute)attributes.First()).Name;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow I think it's exactly the answer I was looking for. I'll try this out as soon as I can and report back to you. Thanks!!

Comment: Ok, so the only error I'm getting now is for the "HasRegionAttribute", which is seems to be missing in your code. How do I add that function?

Comment: Updated the original answer to include the extension methods.

Comment: Everything works!!  I like your use of the Region attribute  :)

My last question. When you display your content in the splitview, do you display Pages or UserControls? I ask because in Android they have MvxFragment<ViewModel>, but in Windows I don't see anything such as MvxUserControl<ViewModel>. 

Thanks for your help!!   :)   Now I can continue from here.

Comment: Just did a PullRequest with a little different presenter, which works a little easier imo, check it out here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/1157/files or read about it on my blog http://stephanvs.com/implementing-a-multi-region-presenter-for-windows-10-uwp-and-mvvmcross/

Comment: That's nice of you to do that, I haven't found any other sample online for such a case. I hope this helps others as well :)

Comment: Actually the updated presenter ships in MvvmCross v4.0-beta4 :D - http://mvvmcross.com/Beta4Release/

Answer (score 1):

As the link to the blog of @Stephanvs is no longer active I was able to pull the content off the Web Archive, i'll post it here for who ever is looking for it:

> **Implementing a Multi Region Presenter for Windows 10 UWP and MvvmCross
> 18 October 2015 on MvvmCross, Xamarin, UWP, Windows 10, Presenter > Universal Windows Platform**
>
> I'm upgrading a Windows Store app to the new Windows 10 Universal
> Windows Platform. MvvmCross has added support for UWP in v4.0-beta2.
>
> A new control in the UWP is the SplitView control. Basically it
> functions as a container view which consist of two sub views, shown
> side-by-side. Mostly it's used to implement the (in)famous hamburger
> menu.
>
> By default MvvmCross doesn't know how to deal with the SplitView, and
> just replaces the entire screen contents with a new View when
> navigating between ViewModels. If however we want to lay-out our views
> differently and show multiple views within one window, we need a
> different solution. Luckily we can plug-in a custom presenter, which
> will take care of handling the lay-out per platform.
>
> **Registering the MultiRegionPresenter**
>
> In the Setup.cs file in your UWP project, you can override the
> CreateViewPresenter method with the following implementation.
>
> ```
> protected override IMvxWindowsViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter(IMvxWindowsFrame rootFrame)  
> {
>     return new MvxWindowsMultiRegionViewPresenter(rootFrame);
> }
> ```
>
> **Using Regions**
>
> We can define a region by declaring a 
> element. At this point it has to be a Frame type because then we can
> also show a nice transition animation when switching views.
>
> ```
> <mvx:MvxWindowsPage ...>  
>     <Grid>
>         <!-- ... -->
>
>         <SplitView>
>             <SplitView.Pane>
>                 <!-- Menu Content as ListView or something similar -->
>             </SplitView.Pane>
>             <SplitView.Content>
>                 <Frame x:Name="MainContent" />
>             </SplitView.Content>
>         </SplitView>
>     </Grid>
> </mvx:MvxWindowsPage>
> ```
>
> Now we want to be able when a ShowViewModel(...) occurs to swap out
> the current view presented in the MainContent frame.
>
> **Showing Views in a Region**
>
> In the code-behind for a View we can now declare a MvxRegionAttribute,
> defining in which region we want this View to be rendered. This name
> has to match a Frame element in the view.
>
> ```
> [MvxRegion("MainContent")]
> public partial class PersonView  
> {
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> It's also possible to declare multiple regions within the same view.
> This would allow you to split up your UI in more re-usable pieces.
>
> **Animating the Transition between Content Views**
>
> If you want a nice animation when transitioning between views in the
> Frame, you can add the following snippet to the Frame declaration.
>
> ```
> <Frame x:Name="MainContent">  
>     <Frame.ContentTransitions>
>         <TransitionCollection>
>             <NavigationThemeTransition>
>                   <NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
>                       <EntranceNavigationTransitionInfo />
>                 </NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
>             </NavigationThemeTransition>
>         </TransitionCollection>
>     </Frame.ContentTransitions>
> </Frame>
> ```
>
> The contents will now be nicely animated when navigating.
>
> Hope this helps, Stephanvs